# Multi-Store development

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Currently with my company we are working with a third party software for multi-store fronts (portals) called ZNode. We have a couple portals/stores set up and the web team we have has set up the portals to use different headers/footers/navigation. The url's for the stores are different in our dev environment (store1.com/shoppingcart.aspx vs store2.com/shoppingcart.aspx) and they have different views of the same page and follow the same navigation set up by the different buttons within the store.

The problem though is that I need to troubleshoot problems for store2.com/shoppingcart.aspx but when I try to do it on the localhost through visual studio's I move between store1 (the main store) and store2 (the one I need to troubleshoot) and I don't know how to stay on store2's portal because when I run the page/project locally through VS the url is of course a localhost link with a port number so I can't stay on the second portal like I need to. I just move between them when I reach a page that is one portal and not the other. And when I reach a page that is shared (like shoppingcart.aspx) I move onto the main store/portal.

I didn't know if anyone had some insight into how I could possibly stay on one and not move between them, if you do thought I would be very interested to try any ideas anyone might have on how to stay on one portal or the other. ***I have asked tech support for the third party vendor but have not heard back yet and I would like to get a jump on trying things while I wait for a response that could take, potentially, a few days***.

Currently, we have to the localhost dev site set up through IIS to run on a certain port with the authentication of our active directly log in. Don't know if this helps or not.

Comment: How does it work on production?  If it is keying off the domain name you could change your hosts file to make your local machine "look" like the production URL

Comment: In dev (the second store isn't rolled out yet) they each act like two different websites. So each has their own url (`http://store1.com` & `http://store2.com`). Think you give an explanation on how to change the host files to do that? I haven't done that before.

Comment: Just add an entry to hosts file that maps `store2.com` to `127.0.0.1` Super User is a better site to ask how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create multiple bindings to the **same** site in iis in your dev machine. Like `store1.com` and `store2.com`. Then map both to your local box in the hosts file (system32/drivers/etc/hosts)

```
127.0.0.1 store1.com
127.0.0.1 store2.com
```

This way your local iis will answer to requests to both domains from the same site.